# How to change F5 key binding on Ubuntu 22.04 laptop

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-22.04

I have installed Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 22.04 and found out that F5 Start Debugging key does not work because it is captured by operation system. It is bound to lower screen brightness function.

How can I disable this operation system key binding?

As a quick fix I have changed keyboard mapping inside VS Code, but I do not like it.
I would rather keep standard VS Code binding and bind Fn+F5 to lower screen brightness, as it is indicated on my laptop keyboard.

Comment: Look in your laptop’s BIOS settings. This is neither a VSCode nor (particularly) an Ubuntu issue, but a hardware/firmware one.

Comment: define a new key binding that uses the same command and `when` as the default `F5` key bind

Comment: Thank you, user3840170! It is BIOS. Your comment resolved the problem.